# Can I install windows 64bit on my other HDD

Tags: windows, hard-drive, installation

I'm currently running 32bit Windows 7 on my 500GB HDD and I want to change over to Windows 64bit on my 1TB HDD. Can I put Windows 64bit on my second 1TB HDD boot into it and just format my old 500GB HDD from there?

Comment: If course just change the boot order

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. 
Change the Boot priorities on the BIOS options so the new-to-be-getting-windows hard drive boots first. 
Then, perform the installation and from inside windows format the other one, or during partitioning itself depending on your needs or preference.

Comment: Thanks I can now empty my 1TB drive on to my 500GB install windows and move the stuff I need back, then format it. Yay more than 4GB of ram